# Data exceeds UNCOMPRESS_DATA_MAX with a small file

Tags: android

There's something that I don't get.
I am testing an app on the emulator, version 2.2 (there is no problem for 2.3).

I have an xml file ("myXml.xml") as an asset, which won't be parsed.

```
context.getResources().getXml(R.xml.myXml);
```

returns:

```
Data exceeds UNCOMPRESS_DATA_MAX (8597616 vs 1048576)
```

However, the xml fils is only 992 136 bytes (995 328 bytes on the disk).
Same thing with extension ".jet".

Is there a way I can know which file has length 8597616 ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Your file size is exceeds that 1 mb so android compressing it.For solution refer below link

http://ponystyle.com/blog/2010/03/26/dealing-with-asset-compression-in-android-apps/